# Json Rest API: Best solution for getting multiple bits of data

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, zend-framework2

I am working on a Restful web service with JSON using Zend Framework 2. And the client side will run on AngularJS. Now I have one big question?

**Description:**

I have a post, and that post contains a style. (My program creates the relation between StyleId and Id)
So my db looks like this

***Posts Table***

- Id
- Name
- StyleId

***Styles Table***

- Id
- Style

**Questions:**

Which of the 3 solutions is the best one (fastest, most performance, best practice):

1. Get all the styles from the `getList()` function but then you have styles that you don't need.
2. Send multiple request to the `get($id)` function to get the styles that I need.
3. Rewrite the `getList()` function from Posts so that I also returns styles like the following json: `{ posts : { id: 1, name: "test", styleId: 1 }, styles: { id: 1, style: "teststyle" }`

If you need more info that I forgot please comment and I will add!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends. We have no idea how much data is contained within each call, current performance of your application, other data needs for the application, bandwidth concerns, etc.

Choose option 1 if you're not concerned about consuming the extra bandwidth. You have to make that call depending on how much extra styling there is.

Choose option 2 if option 1 would consume too much data and the extra requests wouldn't diminish with network performance, etc.

Choose option 3 if neither option 1 or 2 are good fits. And it isn't too inconvenient to rewrite.

Basically, this question is too broad for us to be able to analyze which is going to be the best case for you.

Comment: At this moment the database is still small and normally it will never go over 1000 rows because it is just for my local youth club. Thx for the anwser.